Keep handled conflicts when rebasing a repository and the non-linear history
A variation of a question that has been asked multiple times but I haven't been able to determine a fitting answers that covers my case.
In short I want to rebase a repository without specific commits and preserve already done merge conflicts with minimal effort having a longer history.

Why this question is not a simple duplicate disclaimer:
I know there is Remove commit from history but it is not specific enough for my case, they do not address the case of preserving already done merges and conflicts handled at all.
git rebase -i is not sufficient: merges and how they are handled should be preserved keeping a non-linear history.
While my questions is tightly related to single files, I want to clean commits and git-filter-repo and git rm --cached paired with just rebase or reset are too simple and not what is needed, the git history is not trivial.
That single files are involved should just make the process easier but does not make it trivial.

More details on the problem:
We want to remove several commits from our git history as if they have never been made (we do not just want to clean the files but the commits). Prerequisites:

The helpful part: the removed commits are standalone files that are never touched afterwards.
We want to preserve the git history, keeping the merges and how they were handled for a non-linear history.

The be best thing we found is git rebase -i master --rebase-merges and do a label-onto and drop/remove the commits we do not want.
However this forces us to handle all merge conflicts that were solved in the past again. How can this be avoided, i.e. how can we make a copy if the repository without the commits we want to remove?

Even though the question being marked as a duplicate is in general correct, because of this case being specifically about commits that take care of adding specific files that you would like to keep outside of history, I think the answer I provided there gets a little closer to your requirements.

Keep a list of the files that you want to remove..... so that you can do something like git rm --cached the-list-of-doomed-files at any point. You can do a git rebase interactive --rebase-merges, and remove the commits of the files you want to get rid of.... then, when the rebase starts, and assuming all you want to do is just git rid of those files without additional changes, then you can safely run this every time you find a conflict:
git checkout REBASE_HEAD -- .
git rm --cached the-list-of-dommed-files
GIT_EDITOR=/usr/bin/true git rebase --continue

That should work, at least on paper.

Can you explain the GIT_EDITOR line for me

The rm part is not needed (in this case), as removing the specific commits is enough. It looks like the other two lines do the job. Thank you.

A downside is that it creates strange merge artifacts, some paths are split up multiple times creating many merges making the history problematic to read at some points, i.e.history is not entirely accurate.

If you are removing files from history, then you need to run rm everytime you run into a conflict because given that you are getting the contents of REBASE_HEAD in full, the files might (and will) show up there.

the GIT_EDITOR part is so that you do not have to edit the comment for the commit.... it will take it as it was in the original commit.

Thank you for the explanations. I could track down the strange history to a special branch that has (intentionally) not clean merges that likely needs some special attention in the rebase-todos, but that is not linked to the original problem
